# ASP.NET MVC 2.0 - IList<T> CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, models, model-binding

What is the best way to handle this:

```
class Option {
    int id;
    string name;
}

class QuoteItem
{
     IList<Option> options;
}

class QuoteViewModel {
     IList<Option> allOptions;
     QuoteItem quoteItem;
}
```

Basically, I have all the available options in `allOptions`. I want to have a checkbox that puts another `Option` (even if its just its `id`) into the `QuoteItem.options` list when it is checked.  How would I accomplish this?  Would it best be an `IList<bool>` and bind it after the fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you take look at this [blog entry](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) from Phil Haack about model binding to a list

For your situation you can use simple model binding to a `IEnumerable<int> options`, where the values will be the id of your selected options.

your input view will then look something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/QuoteItems/SetOptions">
        <input type="hidden" name="options" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="options" value="4" />
        <input type="hidden" name="options" value="2" />
        <input type="hidden" name="options" value="8" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

The hidden inputs contain your selected optionId's, note name attribute which is the same for each hidden input. The default model binder can bind this to a list of integers.

The thing you need to do next is adding / removing a hidden options input at client side depending on whether an item is selected in your "all-options" select control.

Comment: That post is quite outdated. I am using MVC 2.0

Comment: I believe it is still valid in MVC 2.0,  at least in preview 1